# How should I store files of user accounts on the server?

Tags: php, database, swift

I'm creating an iOS app which connects to an online server.  The user creates an account, where they can then upload a CSV file and the contents will be displayed in the app.

An initial idea is to create a new directory with each account thats created, the url request will then access that directory and retrieve the requested CSV file.

Is this efficient way to go about it?

Everything else from the user can just be stored in my database so it's just a matter of storing the CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV should not be accessible directly (i.e. http://example.com/csv/0127/example.csv). If they are, people will be able to download files from other accounts. If your server runs Apache you can use a .htaccess to protect the files from beeing download directly.

So it's best to create a little PHP script, that checks if the requesting user is allowed to download that file and then send it to him. The technique used to send the files through PHP differs based on the size of your files.

Storing them as a file on your server is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Storing files on the server is much more efficient than storing them in the database - so yes. The only problem is disk space and what happens if the server goes down?

You would be better to use cloud storage like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) which will help remedy those scenario's and also scale accordingly.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about disk space as a typical CSV file tends to only be less than 1MB and my server can hold up to 100GB.  My host also promises a 99.9% uptime and I have a workaround for if the server is down.  I may look at Amazon S3 in the future if I feel it's required